# Is it possible to refer to future bars in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

Using the history reference operator [] it is possible to refer to historic values. Example :

```
plot(series=close[1])
```

plots the previous bars close.

I want to use a negative value, but it does not work. I want to know tomorrows close. How can it be done?

```
  plot(series=close[-1])
```

Thanks a lot!

Regards
Markus

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know tomorrows close.

Don't we all?

In pine forward referencing is strictly prohibited. Evaluations have to be done from the perspective of the most recent bar that you're evaluating.

For example a three bar pivot (lower high, higher high, lower high). In some other languages you can evaluate using forward referencing, **high > high[1] and high > high[-1]**. This can't be done in pine and so you will have to refactor from the last bar, **high < high[1] and high[1] > high[2]**